# Word-wrapping page-long polynomials in latex

Tags: equations, formatting

I know that you can enter multiline equations using the `align` environment and line breaks (`\\`).

I want to LaTeX multiple polynomials that are very long (up to a page in length, single-spaced and 12 point font) without having to manually insert each line break. Even if I went through the trouble once, I'd have to do it all over again just to reformat the document.

Is there a way to do this, or do I have to use something like the `verbatim` environment or the `listings` environment, where the polynomials just become text?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: you can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Displayed math can't be broken automatically, but in-line math can. So you can try something like

```
\newenvironment{polynomial}
  {\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}%
   \setlength{\leftskip}{\parindent}%
   \setlength{\rightskip}{\leftskip}%
   \medmuskip=4mu plus 2mu minus 2mu
   \binoppenalty=0
   \noindent$\displaystyle}
  {$\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}
```

and put your long polynomial in the newly defined environment.

Answer (score 2):

if you're using `amsmath`, there's a command `\allowdisplaybreaks` that would work in an `align` environment (though not in the `aligned` sub-environment).  it's documented in the [`amsmath` user's guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) on pp.8-9.  the recommendation is to put

```
\allowdisplaybreaks[1]
```

in your preamble if you want it to work throughout the document.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [breqn](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mh/) package, I used it few years back briefly with good results. There is also a [presentation](http://www.latex-project.org/papers/breqn-next-steps.pdf) which shows a few eqs.

(I find it rather inconvenient that docstrip documentation just describe packages without actually *showing* what they output. Sigh.)

Comment: Just found out that there is [breqn tag](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breqn) at tex.stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

You may also use the `breqn` environment to break the equation across many lines.
Example taken from the [`breqn` user guide](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/mh/breqn.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[mathpazo]{flexisym}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

\begin{dmath}[label={sna74}]
  \frac{1}{6} \left(\sigma(k,h,0) +\frac{3(h-1)}{h}\right)
  +\frac{1}{6} \left(\sigma(h,k,0) +\frac{3(k-1)}{k}\right)
  =\frac{1}{6} \left(\frac{h}{k} +\frac{k}{h} +\frac{1}{hk}\right)
  +\frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{2h} -\frac{1}{2k},
\end{dmath}

\end{document}
```

Note that, according to the user guide, the `breqn` class only supports the `mathpazo` and `mathptmx` packages, but that could have changed since the document was written.

Like I mentioned in my previous post, the `dmath` environment is similar to the `equation` environment, except that it supports line breaking and variant numbers (i.e. equation numbering).  To avoid number variants, use the `dmath*` environment.  See the `breqn` user guide for other environments.

Hope this helps (and that the format is easier to read).

Comment: Thanks you for updating your question. Note that you can edit your answers and questions to provide more informations. Please use answers only for solutions to the stated question and address other users in comments. The @ notification only works in comments and the chat anyway. Some formatting tips: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). If you use this the code gets syntax highlighting! Use back-ticks to mark inline code including package names etc.